# Is it correct to conclude $x\notin A \implies x\in\bar{A}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Am I allowed to do this:

$$
x\notin A \implies x\in\bar{A}
$$
($\bar A$ is the set complement) in the context of this proof?

[image]

Comment: depends on context, and on meaning of $\overline A$

Comment: @drhab This is what I'm doing: http://i.imgur.com/1d3auNV.jpg

Comment: To be proved is $B-A\subseteq B\cap\overline{A}$ (so not $B-A\in B\cap\overline{A}$)
where $\overline{A}$ stands for the complement of $A$. There is
only a complement if you are working in some universe/larger set $X$.
So $A,B\subseteq X$ here. Normally not the notation $\overline{A}$
is used but $A^{c}$. Then indeed $x\notin A\Rightarrow x\in A^{c}$
for $x\in X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A,B \subseteq X$ and by $\overline A$ you mean $X \backslash A$, then yes. For $x \in X$, then $x \notin A$ if and only if $x \in \overline A$.

P.S. You shouldn't write $B - A \in B \cap \overline A$ but $B-A \subseteq B \cap \overline A$ (or $B-A \subset B \cap \overline A$, depending on your choice of notation). The terms "being an element of" (i.e. $\in$) and "being a subset of" (i.e. $\subset$ or $\subseteq$) are fundamentally different.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

with the very little information you have provided, I can only guess that $X$ is some element & $A$ is some set and $\bar A$ is complement of $A$. In this case it is true, obviously, because if $X$ is in universal set but not in $A$ it has to be in $\bar A$. And you should write element with small letter i.e. $x$ not $X$

Comment: Um... his $x$ is a small letter. Big $X$'s are bigger.

Answer (score 0):

No I do not think so,

I guess you are trying to say that

$x\notin A \implies x \in \bar{A}$. This is false, lets assume $A = \mathbb{Q}$, and $x\in\mathbb{C}$. Then $x\notin A$ and $x\notin \bar{A}$, since $\bar{A} = \mathbb{R}$. Assuming $\bar{A}$ means the closure of $A$.

Comment: I highly doubt he  means closure here....:P